# Maven + JSP - Why does not show images?

Tags: html, image, jsp, maven

The Browser doesn't display the images.
I added this to my servlet-Context.xml:

```
<mvc:resources mapping="/images/**" location="/images/" />
```

and in the home.jsp:

```
<img src="images/header.png">
```

It does not display the image :( Why?

Answer (score 0):

Use the jstl tag

```
<img src="<c:url value="images/header.png"/>"/>
```

Comment: Is your images folder in the class path? I mean is it located in the `webapp` folder where the `WEB-INF` is present.

Comment: I put the images everywhere.